# How to run Selenium/xUnit tests written in C# from C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xunit.net

What's the best way to run tests (C# .Net Framework 4.7.2) programmatically? I have a service that will kick off ~twice a day that checks to see if there is a new build, if there is it uninstalls the old build and installs the new build and then I need to run the tests that we've written. I was thinking that they needed to be run from the CMD prompt since the last time I did this over a year ago was using Jenkins, but maybe since they are being run from a service I can just call them directly? They are, after all, just C# code in a different .dll. I'd want to capture any failures and report that (perhaps via email).

So what are the best practices for running C# Xunit tests from a C# service? I could just call each method in a try/catch block but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: The best way to do this is to integrate it properly into your standard CI/CD process.

Comment: @DanielMann That sounds great, but since this is a website that needs to be uninstalled/installed after every build (installer is written in InstallShield I don't know how to do that). Our builds run in TFS. So your answer only answers a small part of my question. I can switch what kicks off the build to tbe the build itself (CI) but that doesn't help me call/execute the tests themselves.

Comment: The CI build would execute the tests... why is the web application running tests?

Comment: The CI build can monitor version control for new changes. You might be able to trigger the uninstall/reinstall from the build pipeline.